# Does a star that is far from any galaxy tend to rotate slower?

Tags: angular-momentum, galaxies, stellar-evolution, galaxy-clusters, nebulae

I'm wondering whether the rotation of a galaxy and the buffeting of the gas and dust within it by light and stellar wind and pressure waves makes nebulae or gas clouds in galaxies have more angular momentum than those in intergalactic space, and thus give birth to stars that tend to spin faster than those stars that are in intergalactic space?

Comment: How are the stars born in intergalactic space without all those same phenomena being present?

Comment: @ProfRob I have no idea, but I guess by gravity alone.

Comment: Stars aren't just born in isolation. They surely must be born from turbulent gas clouds. The gas cloud is required to provide a mass reservoir. The turbulence appears to be need to make (parts of) them collapse. Those turbulent clouds fragment and each of the fragments has angular momentum even if the cloud didn't.

Comment: @ProfRob Okay, didn't know that. But is there reason to think that those fragments on average have a lower angular momentum due being formed from gas that had lower angular momentum due not being in a rotating galaxy?